# jasperserver export :java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number

Tags: jasper-reports

All the fields specified in those location are of string type only.

I have added the property

still am gettting this error while exporting jasper report to xlsx file. I have added

```
The server has encountered an error. Please excuse the inconvenience. 
Error Message
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number

Error Trace
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number at   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRAbstractExporter.getNumberCellValue    (JRAbstractExporter.java:1233) at     net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRAbstractExporter.getTextValue(JRAbstractExporter.java:1174) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.ooxml.JRXlsxExporter.exportText(JRXlsxExporter.java:1301) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsAbstractExporter.exportPage(JRXlsAbstractExporter.java:1243) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsAbstractExporter.exportReportToStream(JRXlsAbstractExporter.java:1026) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsAbstractExporter.exportReport(JRXlsAbstractExporter.java:666) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.action.ReportXlsxExporter.export(ReportXlsxExporter.java:106) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.action.AbstractReportExporter.exportBuffered(AbstractReportExporter.java:171) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.action.AbstractReportExporter.export(AbstractReportExporter.java:97) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.action.ReportExporterAction.export(ReportExporterAction.java:147) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at org.springframework.webflow.action.DispatchMethodInvoker.invoke(DispatchMethodInvoker.java:98) at org.springframework.webflow.action.MultiAction.doExecute(MultiAction.java:123) at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188) at org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction.execute(AnnotatedAction.java:145) at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51) at org.springframework.webflow.action.EvaluateAction.doExecute(EvaluateAction.java:77) at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute
```

Suggest me what changes has to be done. If you have faced the same issue.

Comment: you are trying to assign String to number type?

Comment: no its string(alphanumeric) value. when i try to export after displaying in jasperserver then it throws that error